# Trying to read sizeof() returns unexpected result

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

This is my code. As you can probably tell, I am a complete beginner to C++ and especially pointers. I learn by doing, that's why I have those Log() outputs, just helps me see if I am doing everything correctly. I came across a function that reads the size of the variable/datatype, and it kind of confused me here.

If I purposely allocate 8 bytes of memory on the heap to the variable 'buffer', why does sizeof() read 'buffer' as 4 bytes? What am I missing/doing wrong/not understanding here?

```
#include <iostream>

#define Log(message) std::cout << message << std::endl;

int main()
{
char* buffer = new char[8];
Log(sizeof(buffer));

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    *buffer = 10;
    Log("Buffer is a variable that takes up 8 bytes of memory and is located on the heap. It holds 
    the value " << ((std::string*)*buffer) << " located at the memory address " << 
    ((std::string*)&buffer));
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a `char*`. `sizeof` doesnt know about dynamically allocated memory, its pure compile time

Comment: You should get a different result with `char buffer[8];`

Comment: Be careful. You are writing C++ like it is C. This is something you will have to unlearn to write "proper" C++ and the sooner you do it the better!

Comment: @Rerito `sizeof` would yield same result in C and the casts would be wrong in C too

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am well aware of that, I think my comment is still on point.

Comment: If you are learning C++, forget that pointers and `(casts)` exist, for the moment.

Comment: Also `buffer` is "on the stack". It *points to* an object "on the heap". A pointer is not the object it points to, it is it's own thing

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(x)` tells you the size of `x`, not the size of whatever `x`  points to.

On an unrelated note, `x` does not mount to a `std::string` so the cast is wrong.

Suggestion: forget about `new[]`, just use `std::string buffer`. It will manage `new[]` and `delete[]` for you, also when you copy it, add characters, etcetera.

Comment: I've followed your advice and removed new and just initialized it as a string* instead of char = new char[]. How do I make sizeof() read the size of what buffer is pointing to? I've tried adding the * and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ImMalkah: `string*` ? I intentionally wrote `string` - that's not a pointer. Next, read the chapter in your textbook about `std::string`. It has a `.size()` member function.

Comment: I understand... I am currently working with very simple pointers and I'm just trying to understand why sizeof() doesn't return 8 bytes. You told me it's because it's not reading the size of what buffer is pointing to, which I appreciate, now how do I go about doing this the right way, so that sizeof() reads buffer as 8 byes?

Comment: You can't. That information is gone. That's (part of) why we are suggesting not using pointers

Comment: @ImMalkah: If you look at `sizeof(std::string)`, you'll notice that it's bigger than `sizeof(char*)`. One of the reasons for that is that even `std::string` can't calculate `std::string::size` from a single `char*`.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Thank you for going into detail. I understand your guys' advice to not utilize pointers, and I would agree from a beginner's standpoint, but this is not school work, this is just pure learning by trial and error for me, as I learn by making mistake so there's nothing to lose (other than my mind) haha. Thanks again.

Comment: So from what I've understood so far... sizeof(buffer) reads the size of buffer's type (which is char*, not the size of what it's pointing to because that is dynamically allocated at debug correct?

Comment: @ImMalkah: Yes, `sizeof(buffer)` is short for `sizeof(decltype(buffer))`.. This is a **compile-time** constant.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is a pointer object. It *points to* the first element of a `char[8]` object (that has no name), but it itself is a `char *`. On your platform, all pointers occupy 4 bytes. On other common platforms, all pointers occupy 8 bytes.

Note that your program has undefined behaviour because you reinterpret `*buffer` as `std::string*`. A `char` is totally unrelated to `std::string*`.

Comment: I only casted *buffer as a string because if I didn't, the output in the console looked all weird. What would be your suggestion? How should I properly print out the respective values without casting?

Comment: You only initialise the first character of `buffer`, to (on an ASCII system) the line-feed character. Trying to print that has undefined behaviour, as you are reading uninitialised data. I would suggest using `std::string` from the start

Comment: I've changed char* buffer = new char[8] to std::string* buffer[8] and removed casting, and it still prints out as it was before, so thank you for that! Now my question is... why is sizeof() reading 32 now?

Comment: No, `std::string buffer(8);` You have declared 8 pointers to strings, and then set the value of those pointers to an arbitrary number. Stop guessing things. C++ is not a safe language to guess in

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just a beginner trying to learn. Could you clarify what you mean? Also, std::string buffer(8) returns an error... guessing because I'm assigning an int to a string?

Comment: Oops, should be `std::string buffer(8, 'a');` (or whatever character you want to initialise it with)